# ArrayFormula for the google form

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

So I have a four(4) columns/fields the in my google sheets that link to a google form, these are,

1. **Last_Name**
2. **Given_Name**
3. **Middle_Name**

The only fields that the user will fill up are the first three(3) fields.

on my 4th column, is the **Full_Name**, now I want to combine the three(3) fields as one(1) using ArrayFormula?

this is my formula, `=ARRAYFORMULA(E2&" "&F2&" "&G2)`, every time I save some records, the formula gone on that specific field.

[This is my spreadsheet, that connected to a form](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XZBrmrR3E1QS8Orbq4STQlN2QtLcgGHj30oUk3bH7Yc/edit#gid=1400541998)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), E2:E&" "&F2:F&" "&G2:G,))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer MR. @JVP , but what i'm looking is like this. The formula will be put in the cell 'H2:H', 

Ex. the value of the 
LAST_NAME = "FRANCISO", 
GIVEN_NAME = "RABAL" 
MIDDLE_NAME = "IBAÑEZ" , 

now on the cell 'H2' it will be 

FULL_NAME = "FRANCISCO RABAL IBAÑEZ".

Comment: The formula should be doing exactly that. Note that per your locale you'll have to change the comma to a semicolon. Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet?

Comment: Can you share a  link to an editable copy in your post (and remove it afterward?

Comment: Please check the updated question sir, and got another problem in my other   project,. if you can help me? this is the link of my question here in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191248/drop-down-dependent-menus-in-google-spreadsheets